# Kotlin multiple variables Null checker method implementation

Tags: kotlin

I have multiple variables that can be nullable and i need to check them ( Strings and Dates ) .

I need a method where i pass it X number of variables and it returns me a list of the variables that are null.

I was thinking something that i can call like this :

```
internal fun checkNullVariables ( var x, var y , ..... ) : MutableList<String>{

    // yada yada

    return listOfNamesOfNullVariables
}
```

Comment: what do you want the function to return - the names of variables that are null?

Comment: If you return only the null variables you will just get a list of nulls.. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: please show the desired output and an example of input

Comment: I would probably go for a `Map`, i.e.: `fun checkNullVariables(map : Map<String, Any?>) = map.filterValues { it == null }.keys`... which you then can call like: `checkNullVariables(mapOf("x" to x, "y-var" to y, "whatever" to whatever"))` giving you back all the keys that have a `null`-value... or if you have a map already, just: `checkNullVariables(yourMap)`

Comment: Yes, i want a list of the names of the variables that are null as return so that then i can send a warning with those names on the console. That map could be a solution, isn't there a way to do it without giving a list but only giving directly the variables into the method?

Comment: the approach you are aiming can be achieved by using reflection, but it is not recommended in any case. Instead of explicitly checking whether a value is null or not, use `!!` and `?` operator.

Comment: @Alex I assume you want something as generic as possible.. but then, your current signature isn't really appropriate... you may want to tell, what you are really after... maybe there is a more appropriate solution to it then you can think of at the moment... at the moment both reflection as also properties backed by map seem appropriate to me... but I can also think of a rather static variant that may solve your issue ...

Answer (score 1):

This definitely requires reflection, since you want parameter names. You need to add reflection as a dependency [as explained in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) to use the below code.

```
private fun listNullProperties (vararg props: KProperty0<Any?>) : List<String> {
    val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (prop in props)
        if (param.get() == null)
            list.add(param.name)
    return list
}
```

Usage:

```
val nullPropertiesByName = listNullParameters(
    ::myProperty,
    ::myOtherProperty,
    ::myDateProperty
)
println(nullPropertiesByName.joinToString())
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm just taking a guess myself that OP is using this only for debugging purposes during development and is trying to save typing.

Comment: hmmm... then I would probably just overwrite `toString` to fit the purpose ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about logging, you *could*:

```
fun <T> T?.logNull(name: String) {
    when(this) {
        null -> //log '$name' was null
        else -> //do nothing
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
var a: String? = null
a.logNull("my a variable") // "'my a variable' was null"
```

Comment: No, i don't need to log it. I just need the list of names of Null variables to do stuff later. This implementation doesn't solve my main problem that is avoiding an endless series of ifs to check nulls 1by1.

Comment: Then it totally makes no sense.

Comment: :((((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend the `Map`-approach. You may want to use [properties stored in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) to overcome the use of reflection.

Here is an example using a type with 2 dates and 2 strings, both having a nullable and a non-null variant:

```
class YourData(internal val backedMap : Map<String, Any?>) {
  val beginDate : Date by backedMap
  val endDate : Date? by backedMap
  val maybeString : String? by backedMap
  val string : String by backedMap
  constructor(beginDate : Date, string : String, endDate: Date? = null, maybeString : String? = null) : this(mapOf(
      "beginDate" to beginDate,
      "endDate" to endDate,
      "maybeString" to maybeString,
      "string" to string
  ))
}
```

While it may seem more complicated having that additional constructor in place, it just helps to easily create new objects the way you are most comfortable with.

Now you can either supply that function I placed in the comment or any variant of it. I now use an extension function for `YourData` instead:

```
fun YourData.getKeysWithNullValues() = backedMap.filterValues { it == null }.keys
```

Usage then may look as follows:

```
YourData(Date(), "test string")
  .getKeysWithNullValues()
  .forEach(::println)
```

which for this example would print:

```
endDate
maybeString
```